# Installing ADT on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, adt

On Eclipse Indigo 64-bit, I tried to install ADT (Android Development Tools) plugin ver 15.0. But I get this error :

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software currently installed: Shared profile
>   1.0.0.1316138720972 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138720972)   Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1316138720972 (SharedProfile_epp.package.java 1.0.0.1316138720972) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.100.20110804-1717]' but it could not be found

Do I need to install an eclipse dependency ?

Comment: Do you **have** to use 64 bit? I've had nothing but problems with 64 bit Eclipse.

Comment: ADT PLugin worked fine with Eclipse Helios 64 bit. So I dont think this has to do with the 64-bit part.

Answer (score 5):

I installed eclipse into /opt as root. I had this exact issue.

Seems that this has something to do with permissions (Yeah, great error message, I know).

I simply installed the plugins while running eclipse as root:

```
user@computer ~$ sudo eclipse &
```

Problem solved!

EDIT:
Instead of this, when you install it, you can change the ownership of the eclipse files so that you don't have to run as super user every time you want to install an addon.

```
user@computer /opt $ sudo chown -R user eclipse/
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an Eclipse bug, see:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350645

You shouldn't need to be administrator to install additional plugins...

Answer (score 1):

Alright... this solved my problem:

1. Open Eclipse
2. Go to Help > Install New Software > click on Available Software Sites.
3. Make sure that "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo" is checked.
4. Then.. enable the "contact all update sites.." option on the Install new software page.

You should be all set!

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the "contact all update sites.." option on the Install new software page.

That said, ADT should not have a dependency on epp packages, unless you have some other software installed along with Eclipse. Please make sure you're using one of the following Eclipse versions:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Eclipse Classic (versions 3.5.1 and higher)
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Follow instructions on http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Run Eclipse with administrator priviledges... If on Windows right click, and select run as admin

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the SDK archive and follow these instructions, it worked for me.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting

1. Download the ADT Plugin zip file (do not unpack it):
2. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
3. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
4. In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
5. Select the downloaded ADT-21.0.0.zip file and click OK.
6. Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
7. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
8. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
9. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.

If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.

Lastly, when the installation completes, restart Eclipse.